# MySQL - How to combine 2 tables in a query when one table may not have a corresponding row

Tags: mysql, node.js, wordpress, join

I am writing a basic CMS system with NodeJS and MySQL.  I am using the tables structure for posts that WordPress also uses, that being 'posts' and 'post_meta'.

The 'posts' table has the following columns...

```
id
post_title
post_date
...etc
```

The 'post_meta' table has the following columns...

```
id
post_id - ID of associated post
meta_key
meta_value
```

I like this style as it keeps my rows easy to read in a SQL editor without having to scroll as long lengths, as well as add additional meta data as needed.

Using JOINs (Query below) I am able to make a result set that contains the values from 'posts', as well as additional columns named after 'post_meta.meta_key' that contain the value of 'post_meta.meta_value'.

The problem I am currently running into is how I would go about returning results where a 'meta_key' is not present in the 'posts_meta' table, and instead filling that column of the result with NULL.

Example usage.  2 Posts are in the 'posts' table, the first has 2 meta_keys associated with it, the other has only 1.

**'posts' table contents**

```
id : 1
title : 'Post 1'
post_date : 'timestamp of posted date/time'

id : 2
title : 'Post 2'
post_date : 'timestamp of posted date/time'
```

**'posts_meta' table contents**

```
id : 1
post_id : 1
meta_key : 'key1'
meta_value : 'key1 value'

id : 2
post_id : 1
meta_key : 'key2'
meta_value : 'key2 value'

id : 3
post_id : 2
meta_key : 'key1'
posts_meta.meta_value : 'key1 value'
```

the results I would like to get from this are

```
post_id : 1
title : 'Post 1'
post_date : 'timestamp of posted date/time'
key1 : 'key1 value'
key2 : 'key2 value'

post_id : 2
title : 'Post 2'
post_date : 'timestamp of posted date/time'
key1 : 'key1 value'
key2 : NULL
```

However, with the code I am currently working with, the second result (Post 2) does not return as part of the results, only 'Post 1', since all of the meta_keys that were being tested for exist in the 'post_meta' table.

Here is my SQL code as it currently stands (edited to keep to the example above)

```
SELECT
    posts.id,
    posts.title,
    posts.post_date,
    m1.meta_value as `key1`,
    m2.meta_value as `key2`
FROM posts
LEFT JOIN post_meta as m1 ON ( posts.id = m1.post_id )
LEFT JOIN post_meta as m2 ON ( posts.id = m2.post_id )
WHERE
    ( m1.meta_key = 'key1' )
    AND ( m2.meta_key = 'key2' )
ORDER BY posts.post_date DESC
```

as you can see, i am selecting the meta_values from the 2 JOINs, and naming them after the specific key each of those joins is being used to retrieve (as defined in the WHERE clause).

I know it has got to be something simple, since I am almost there.  It returns rows that have both key1 and key2, but not rows that are completely missing either or all of them.  I want it to return all rows, and if a key is missing, fill that field in the row with NULL

Comment: `full outer join`, probably. `A left join B` would return all records from A, and any matching records from B. if no records in B are available, the B fields would be nulled. but if there's no A records, then left join won't "create" those for you.

Comment: Full Outer Join is not part of MySQL

Answer (score 1):

You want `FULL OUTER JOIN` rather than `LEFT JOIN`.

`Left Join` will not include rows that do not exist in the other table.  In order to have the data (even if it is NULL).  You need to do a `FULL OUTER JOIN`, that will give you cells with NULL rather than leaving them off entirely.

Since you are using MySQL, you will have to emulate the behavior of a `FULL OUTER JOIN` using `UNION`.  Something like this:

```
SELECT
    posts.id,
    posts.title,
    posts.post_date,
    m1.meta_value as `key1`,
    m2.meta_value as `key2`
FROM posts
LEFT JOIN post_meta as m1 ON ( posts.id = m1.post_id )
LEFT JOIN post_meta as m2 ON ( posts.id = m2.post_id )
WHERE
    ( m1.meta_key = 'key1' )
    AND ( m2.meta_key = 'key2' )
ORDER BY posts.post_date DESC
UNION
SELECT
    posts.id,
    posts.title,
    posts.post_date,
    m1.meta_value as `key1`,
    m2.meta_value as `key2`
FROM posts
RIGHT JOIN post_meta as m1 ON ( posts.id = m1.post_id )
LEFT JOIN post_meta as m2 ON ( posts.id = m2.post_id )
WHERE
    ( m1.meta_key = 'key1' )
    AND ( m2.meta_key = 'key2' )
ORDER BY posts.post_date DESC
UNION
SELECT
    posts.id,
    posts.title,
    posts.post_date,
    m1.meta_value as `key1`,
    m2.meta_value as `key2`
FROM posts
RIGHT JOIN post_meta as m1 ON ( posts.id = m1.post_id )
RIGHT JOIN post_meta as m2 ON ( posts.id = m2.post_id )
WHERE
    ( m1.meta_key = 'key1' )
    AND ( m2.meta_key = 'key2' )
ORDER BY posts.post_date DESC
```

[image: SQL Join Table]

Comment: since i am using MySQL, I am unable to use 'FULL OUTER JOIN', as that is not part of MySQL

Comment: @Rob Updated to take into account MySQL support.

Comment: Great!  After finding out FULL OUTER JOIN was not in MySQL, most of the topics pointed at UNION being what I needed, and your update confirmed it.  Second question, if the example was expanded to more meta_keys, say 3 or 4, how would the RIGHT/LEFT joins need to be written.  I see the above has left/left, right/left, right/right.  What would 3 keys require, or 4, or 5?

Comment: Been trying the code example you gave but it is still not returning any results for the post that does not have key2.  Ill continue to do research on what the issue may be